# How to get value from Map<TestClass,Object> in item label

Tags: jsf, dictionary, jsf-2, selectonemenu

Below is the jsf code

```
  <h:selectOneMenu>
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.mapObject}"var="entity" 
  itemValue="#{entity.key}" itemLabel="#{entity.value.code}"/> 
  </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Backing bean has map defined as

```
 private Map<TestClass, Object> mapObject;
```

TestClass has two variables and getters/setters

```
 String code;
 String name;
```

Issue I am having is : On JSF, on Selectonemenu, for itemLabel i would like to display the TestClass String value i.e code should be displayed.

Presently on SelectOneMenu on UI, I am getting

```
 TestClass[code=t,name=anu] on the drop down, instead i want code value i..e 't'
```

Please let me know how to acheive this.

Comment: BalusC m u got an answer? U edited something.

Comment: I have read your blog it seems more of map object directly. I want String value to be displayed Please help.

Comment: What do you mean with "m" and "u"? Can you please write words full out as you've learnt on primary school? This is not a disney.com chat box or so. And yes, I posted an answer. You don't  need to whine with "please help". It's not up to you to decide whether one would post an answer or not.

Comment: 'm' is just typing mystake( not disney language)  and I saw an update on my question( saying you edited). So, was wondering if there was any change made that I am not seeing. And I am being polite and asking for answers. Y so disrespect !

Comment: Sorry, but text speak is interpreted here as disrespectful. Also that "Y". Just try to not do that :) See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<f:selectItems var>` should in case of maps specify the `Map.Entry`. The `<f:selectItems value>` should therefore specify `Collection<Map.Entry>`. This is not natively recognized yet when you just specify a `Map` (will come in JSF 2.3).

You basically need to explicitly set the value to [`Map#entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) as below in case you intend to use map key as item value and ma:

```
<h:selectOneMenu>
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.mapObject.entrySet()}"var="entry" 
        itemValue="#{...}" itemLabel="#{...}" /> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) object has `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods which return respectively the map entry's key and map entry's value, which are in your case respectively `TestClass` and `Object`. You seem to want to display the `code` property of `TestClass` as item label. So, this should do:

```
<h:selectOneMenu>
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.mapObject.entrySet()}"var="entry" 
        itemValue="#{...}" itemLabel="#{entry.key.code}" /> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

You're not terribly clear on what exactly you'd like to use as item value, so I've left it open.

#### See also:

- [Our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `itemlabel` attribute, (with current value `entity.value.code`). **It should be replaced by `entity.key.code`** ?

Also the `value` needs to call the method `.entrySet` , because the map in itself is not a collection.

```
<h:selectOneMenu>
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.mapObject.entrySet()}" var="entry" 
     itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.key.code}"/> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**Alternatively**, since it's the key you want, you could **iterate the keys immediately.**

```
<h:selectOneMenu>
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.mapObject.keySet()}" var="key" 
     itemValue="#{key}" itemLabel="#{key.code}"/> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: I tried but it doenst work. It seems it is not taking anything that i put in itemvalue or itemLabel. SelectOneMenu , SelectItems is displaying based on value attribute only. For MAP Object

Comment: You are also right partially , as it works only if I use bean.mapObject.entrySet() as value attribute. Thanks,

Comment: Was just adding that :) we crossed eachother. But I have to admit that BalusC beat me to it. I only realized on a second reading.

Comment: Thanks . You are being very polite.